# Moment.js `Y` vs `YYYY`

Tags: momentjs

I was looking at the Moment.js docs and it appears that the `YYYY` (four "Y"s) format string token represents the year, but will only use the set `1970 1971 ... 2029 2030` whereas `Y` (a single "Y") will use the set `1970 1971 ... 9999 +10000 +10001` (using the ISO 8601 standard for dates past the year 9999).

Am I reading the docs wrong? Is there any reason why I would want to use the `YYYY` version if it will stop working for dates past 2030?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are wrong, I'll quote from the docs:

`YYYY   4 or 2 digit year`

Means you will need to specify a year number with 4 (like 1992) or 2 (92) digits

while:

`Y  Year with any number of digits and sign`

It means that for a `Y` you can specify as year number with any number of digits

```
moment("12/25/12995", "MM-DD-YYYY").format("MM-DD-YYYY")
// "12-25-1299"
moment("12/25/12995", "MM-DD-Y").format("MM-DD-Y")
// "12-25-+12995"
```

It also doesn't constrain you to 2030.